# Dismiss modalviewcontroller with a page curl

Tags: iphone, curl, model-view-controller

I am trying to dismiss a modalviewcontroller with a page curl. The curl works okay but I cannot seem to get the tableview under the modalviewcontroller to show up. The image of the modalviewcontroller is still under the curled away page. If I dismiss the modalviewcontoller before the animation finishes the animation doesn't show up. Here is my code:

```
//hide splash screen
- (void)hideSplash{
 [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
 //change to set the time
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
 [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
 [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:modelView cache:NO];
 // do your view swapping here

 //[[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];

 [UIView commitAnimations];
//[self.view  sendSubviewToBack:self.view]; 

}
```

Hope someone can help! Cheers Nick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS4:

To present, it's something like:

```
[containerView addSubview:modelView];
[UIView transitionWithView:containerView
                  duration:.75
                   UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                animations:^{}
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    NSLog(@"finished %d", finished);
                }];
```

To dismiss, use `UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown`.

Answer (score 3):

Your setAnimationTransition: shouldn't be forView:modelView; it should be for the parentView.

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:containerView cache:NO];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html

> If you want to change the appearance
>   of a view during a transition—for
>   example, flip from one view to
>   another—then use a container view, an
>   instance of UIView, as follows:
>
> - Begin an animation block.
> - Set the
>     transition on the container view.
> - Remove the subview from the container
>     view.
> - Add the new subview to the
>     container view.
> - Commit the animation
>     block.
>
> Use of this method is
>   discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. You
>   should use the block-based animation
>   methods instead.